# Is it possible to solve this probability question without knowing if these two events are independent or not?

Tags: probability

The question gives

P(A) = 1/3, P(B) = 1/4 and P(A⋂B) = 1/6 and asks for P(A⋃B<sup>C</sup>)

The solution provided is the following:

P(A∪B<sup>c</sup>) = P(A) +P(B<sup>c</sup>)−P(A∩B<sup>c</sup>)

=P(A) +P(B<sup>c</sup>)−(P(A)−P(A∩B))

=P(B<sup>c</sup>) +P(A∩B) = 11/12

My question is, how can you conclude that

P(A∩B<sup>c</sup>) = P(A)−P(A∩B)

without knowing that

P(A∩B<sup>c</sup>) = P(A)P(B<sup>c</sup>)

= P(A)(1 - P(B)) 
= P(A) - P(A)P(B)

which implies that P(A) and P(B) are independent of each other, as well as implying that P(B<sup>c</sup>) and P(A) are independent of each other

Which is clearly not true given that the problem prompt ( P(A) = 1/3, P(B) = 1/4, but P(A⋂B) = 1/6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, observe that

$$
P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c) = P(A),
$$

which holds for all events, regardless of independence.